# Visual studio c++ based exe doesn't do nothing

Tags: c++, visual-studio

My c++ application in visual studio 2015 runs perfectly. It uses an input file and generates a bunch of other files.

When I try to use the .exe file from the Release folder, it disappears. And when I run it from cmd, it does nothing..

Maybe it's to little information I can give you but.. I don't really know how to explain it better...

Comment: If you start the program from the IDE, it is possible that the execution path is different from the path where the executable is located, which probably is the execution path if you use `cmd` for execution. What do you mean by _it disappears_? Does the file get deleted? Furthermore, If you start from the IDE, you might have some command line arguments configured which are missing when you start from Windows Exlorer.

Comment: What the progradm does? Does it need command line inputs? What is the expected output and the actual one? You have these and a LOT more details you need to provide for us to understand what's your problem

Comment: No the input file path is set from the code. And I meant the windows dissapears when I run the .exe separately.

Comment: I should mention, that the .exe creates the output files, but are empty. And furthermore, it should print some things in the command line, while it creates the output files.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems that might lead to this so I cannot give a full answer, but most issues come from:

- using relative path, current working dir is defined in project properties->debugging->working directory and by default is project dir

**Solve:** 
Review the code for filenames loaded without using full directory path. Copy those files in your relese folder (the folder structure relative to release for these files, must be identical to the one relative to vcxproj

- using dll-s that have path configured in IDE but not in windows.

**Solve:** 
Use depends to find them and copy near the exe: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can still debug it. I think you could run it but it immediately terminate.
Place breakpoint at beginning of code `__asm{ int 3 }` or `__debugbreak()`. It will crash immediately and now you can attach debugger and continue with debugging to observe what's going on.

Also you could turn off optimization for release to debug it easily.